# Yesod, Hamlet, generating tag attributes by condition

Tags: haskell, yesod

What is the better way to generate HTML tag attributes by condition. I have an external function in the module, which can give me some value (Bool for example). And based on that I need or don't need add a class to the tag. this element has children.

```
<tr *class should be here*>
  <td>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Hamlet allows to apply functions within an interpolation, you can simply use the function. Sample demo:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.Hamlet (shamlet)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)

myClass :: Bool -> String
myClass _ = "dummyClass"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ renderHtml [shamlet|
 <tr .#{myClass True}>
   <td> dummy text |]
```

In ghci:

```
λ> main
<tr class="dummyClass"><td> dummy text </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! Functions works before hamlet will translated into plain HTML, ok.